# Модифицируйте код

Tags: python, оптимизация

Один из простейших форматов таблиц — CSV, что значит Comma-Separated Values, т. е. «значения, разделённые запятыми». В самом деле, в этом текстовом формате каждому ряду таблицы соответствует строка текста, а значения в ячейках одного ряда разделяются запятыми.

Придумайте такую модификацию формата CSV, описанного выше, чтобы значения в ячейках таблицы могли содержать запятые и символы перехода на новую строку.

Напишите программу, которая считывает таблицу в формате CSV, *в том числе с запятыми и символами перехода на новую строку* в вашем улучшенном формате, а затем выводит отдельные её элементы.

**Формат ввода**
На первой строке указано одно натуральное число R — число рядов таблицы.
Далее следуют R строк, представляющие ряды таблицы.
Далее следует одно натуральное число N — число элементов таблицы, которые нужно будет вывести.
Далее следует N строк, на которых приведены разделённые запятой координаты элементов таблицы (номер строки и номер столбца, нумерация с нуля).

(Запятые в примере расставлены не по правилам пунктуации.)

Запятые и символы перехода на новую строку (а также, возможно, какие-то ещё символы) кодируются предложенным вами способом.

**Формат вывода**
Выводятся N строк — соответствующие значения из таблицы.

Помните, что пользователь должен видеть запятые как запятые и переходы на новую строку как переходы на новую строку.

написал такой код:

```
table = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    row = [el for el in input().split(',')]
    table.append(row)
for i in range(int(input())):
    a, b = map(int, input().split(","))
    print(table[a][b], end='\n')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть *маленькая ошибка* при выполнении работы программы: она не считывает запятые и пробелы/табуляции, а разделяет и добавляет по ним в матрицу.  И получается если убрать разделение по этим символам,то не будет добавляться в матрицу

Comment: А вы сделали "Придумайте такую модификацию формата CSV"?

Comment: @в этом то и проблема что я не знаю как это реализовать, т.е. то что я описал в конце вопроса свою проблему

Comment: Может быть, это как-то в оригинальном CSV сделано? Не может быть чтобы в CSV за столько лет ни одной запятой не было.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет, в оригинальном такого не просят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мое решение. Если я  правильно понял, что надо. Формально знак & можно заменить на любой  спецсимвол. Если препод не шибко придирчивый - то у вас прокатит.

```
# Правила ввода новая строка - &n, табуляция &t, запятая &c
# например, при вводе Вася&с&n вымой&c пожалуйста&c посуду&t! программа выведет
# Вася,
# Вымой, пожалуйста, посуду  !
r = int(input())
tabl = [input().split(",") for _ in range(r)]
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(len(tabl[i])):
        while "&n" in tabl[i][j] or "&t" in tabl[i][j] or "&c" in tabl[i][j]:
            if "&n" in tabl[i][j]:
                tabl[i][j] = tabl[i][j][:tabl[i][j].find("&n")] +\
                    "\n" + tabl[i][j][tabl[i][j].find("&n") + 2:]
            if "&t" in tabl[i][j]:
                tabl[i][j] = tabl[i][j][:tabl[i][j].find("&t")] +\
                    "\t" + tabl[i][j][tabl[i][j].find("&t") + 2:]
            if "&c" in tabl[i][j]:
                tabl[i][j] = tabl[i][j][:tabl[i][j].find("&c")] +\
                    "," + tabl[i][j][tabl[i][j].find("&c") + 2:]
n = int(input())
x = 0
y = 0
for i in range(n):
    x, y = [int(i) for i in input().split(",")]
    print(tabl[x][y])
```

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что ошибка не та, которую вы описали. Проблема в выводе. Вот что видно при запуске вашей программы:

```
4
Дама,сдавала в багаж
диван, чемодан, саквояж
картину корзину картонку
и маленькую собачонку,,
4
0,0
Дама
1,2
 саквояж
3,1

3,0
и маленькую собачонку
```

От вас, вероятно, хотят это:

```
4
Дама,сдавала в багаж
диван, чемодан, саквояж
картину корзину картонку
и маленькую собачонку,,
4
0,0
1,2
3,1
3,0
Дама
 саквояж


и маленькую собачонку
```

Comment: ну как в примере, вопрос то как добавлять в список с запятыми и табуляциями

Comment: нет, с тем то что вы написали , все нормально, на это не ругается, проблема в этом _которая считывает таблицу в формате CSV, в том числе с запятыми и символами перехода на новую строку_

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
table = [input().split(',')  for i in range(n)]
 
for i in range(int(input())) :
    a, b = map(int, input().split(","))
    if a < n and b < len(table[a]) :
            print(table[a][b], end='\n')
            continue
    print()
```

модифицировал, что вроде как проблема поставленная в вопросе исправлена